# Java Array Constructor Parameter

Tags: java, arrays

I want to add a "path" to my Path object without explicit creating a variable. Why is it not working?

**Doesnt work:**

```
Path path = new Path({ new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0)};);




    public class Path {

        public Point[] Path;

        public Path(Point[] path){
            Path = path;
        }

}
```

When writing `Point[] route = { new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0)};`
and add route to my Path it is working....

**Works:**

```
        Path path = new Path(route);
```

Can someone help me, I don't get this java syntax or problem or w.e

Comment: Why the downvotes instead of helping?!

Comment: Because you haven't tried to find the answer yourself.

Comment: If you don't want to be downvoted, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{ new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0)}` syntax only works as part of an array variable declaration.

You can use :

```
Path path = new Path(new Point[] { new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0)});
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried...

```
Path path = new Path(new Point[] { new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a semi colon inside the statement

```
 Path path = new Path({ new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0)};);
```

It needs to be

```
 Path path = new Path(new Point[] { new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0)});
```